# RolesAllowed and antMatchers.hasRole are returning access denied caused by @Order

Tags: spring-boot

I restricted `/api/topics` and `GET: /api/users` to admins only and when I try to access them, I'm getting the following message:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-04-05T09:26:49.938+0000",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Access Denied",
    "path": "/api/topics"
}
```

It is caused by `@Order(2)` under WebSecurityConfiguration, but if I remove the @Order annotation, `antMatchers.permitAll` won't let me visit any REST endpoint without a token. That's the message:

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```

More information about @Order [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security-oauth2-resource-server.html#oauth2-boot-resource-server-filter-order). And you can check my previous thread [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61031784/antmatchers-permitall-doesnt-let-me-visit-the-rest-point).

The order is totally messed up. Any ideas how to solve it?

It works if I do the following instead of antMatches.permitAll but then what is the point of permitAll and that entire http configuration?

```java
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/topics/**");
}
```

#### Full code:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
@Order(2)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/topics/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/api/users/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient("trusted")
                .secret(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode("secret"))
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "get_token", "refresh_token")
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .autoApprove(true)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(15 * 60)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(30 * 60);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration {

}

// UserController.java
@RolesAllowed("ADMIN")
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<UserDTO>> getAll() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(userMapper.toUserDTOs(userService.getAll()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to `authenticated()` after `hasRole()`

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/topics/**").hasRole("ADMIN").authenticated() // You need to authenticate here
                .antMatchers("/api/users/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't let me, but it might not be the reason because @RolesAllowed is behaving likewise.

Comment: I also tried removing `.anyRequest().authenticated()` and it still says Access denied. It is probably the resource server, but idk.

Comment: @nop check `@RolesAllowed("ROLE_ADMIN")` or `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")` working or not ?

Comment: If you don't use `@RolesAllowed` is it okay then ?

Comment: Could it be the @Order? https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security-oauth2-resource-server.html#oauth2-boot-resource-server-filter-order

Comment: Can you try `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")` this then we understand is there any problem with role or not ?

Comment: Same. It is something else. If I input an invalid token, it should say "Invalid token ..." but it still says Access denied.

Comment: The @Order(2) is causing it. How do I solve it? If I remove Order(2), then antMatches won't work.

Comment: Edited the question and removed the rest of my assumptions.